# How do you ensure column content stays on top within a row of columns?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a flutter layout that consists of a row and a couple of columns.

```
Row(
    children:[
        Column(),
        Column()
    ]
)
```

The first column consists of 1 container, the second column can have x number of containers.

If the second column only has 1 container then the containers from both align as desired.

```
Column1      Column2
ImgContainer TextContainer
```

The problem is when column 2 has multiple containers I start to see the following behavior

```
Column1      Column2
             TextContainer1
ImgContainer TextContainer2
             TextContainer3
```

The container in column 1 starts to center vertically.  I would like it to stay at the top.

I've tried setting `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start` and `verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down` on both columns hoping that would do the trick.  Unfortunately I'm still seeing the same behavior.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking I had to set the axis properties on the columns, but I actually needed to set them on the row.

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children:[
        Column(),
        Column()
    ]
)
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

did you also try this:

```
 Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [],
 )
```

Comment: Oh I just had the thought, that I should try it (`crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`) on the row.  And that worked.